# How to show line before code breaks in GDB

Tags: gdb

When I use GDB there are some instances where GDB tells me what line the code broke on and there are some times when it doesn't say anything beyond a generic error that I just don't understand.

Is there any way to see the last line of code that was executed before the program broke? For example, if line 50 causes a seg fault or the program to break, is there a way for GDB to show line 49 automatically?

Comment: Pleasse show us the error you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, if line 50 causes a seg fault or the program to break, is there a way for GDB to show line 49 automatically?

When you get `SIGSEGV` on line 50, GDB will stop. If you use `list` command, it will show you a window around line 50, which will also include line 49.

Note however, that there is absolutely no guarantee that the last line executed before line 50 was line 49.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `list` to show lines before you get an error.

If it is a segmentation fault, sometimes you need to find the right frame in frame stack.
you use `backtrace` or `bt` to find where the frame you are, then use `up` and `down` to move.

A frame in library codes do not contain useful symbol table for GDB to indicate your error and most of bugs are happened inside the code you wrote, not standard library codes.

As soon as you get the right frame, you list the corresponding code before error.